# Useless server call while combine filter with withLatestFrom

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I have this observable :

```
const myObservable = Observable.combineLatest(v1, v2)
    .filter(([v1, v2]: [boolean, boolean]) => v1 && v2)
    .withLatestFrom(myServerCall)
    .subscribe((data) => { 
        console.log(data);
    });
```

Where myServercall is an http request.

I don't want to make an http call when my filters are not ok. But it always call my server even if it never come inside my subscribe function.

What can I do to avoid useless server call ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `withLatestFrom` isn't a good choice because it subscribes to all source Observables (this means `myServerCall` as well) and that's where it makes the remote call you don't want.

I think `switchMap` makes more sense here.

```
const myObservable = Observable.combineLatest(v1, v2)
    .filter(([v1, v2]: [boolean, boolean]) => v1 && v2)
    .switchMap(() => myServerCall())
    .subscribe((data) => { 
        console.log(data);
    });
```

Comment: Wow thanks ! I didn't know that !
I've done that this way to keep my filters on my subscribe, but I can give them inside a switchMap !